# spring oauth2 client credentials token uniqueness

Tags: oauth-2.0, unique, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I am using client credentials flow using Spring OAuth2. The DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator stores the access_token in memory for me. However if I run multiple client instances from different hosts and make the /oauth/token client_credentials grant request, I get the SAME access token. So all client instances with the same (client id and client secret) get the same access token. So I must be misunderstanding something fundamentally. Is there a way to have each instance of my client receive its own unique client credentials flow access token with it's own expiration period ? The reason I want this is so I can authenticate the client itself before a user account has been created. After the user account is created I can use the user resource password grant flow to get a user specific access_token.

Comment: I guess you need to replace the `DefaultAuthenticationKeyGenerator` with one of your own? But where is it going to get the additional information to make the token unique? You client has to send something in the request otherwise there's no way to identify it.

Comment: That's what I thought. Will give it a try and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Must each key be unique? After all, can't you just give a new access token on each request? Is it required to re-use access tokens?